# How to get cookie in _document.js in NextJS

Tags: cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering

```js
import NextDocument, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head />
      <body className='bgimg darkMode'>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
export default Document
```

I want to get cookie in this page so I can assign dynamic className to the body, so i cant change theme dynamically.
 I tried get it using `Document.getInitialProps`

```js
Document.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const initialProps = await NextDocument.getInitialProps(ctx)
  console.log('ctx', ctx);
  return { ...initialProps, req: ctx }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Document, { Head, Html, Main, NextScript, type DocumentContext, type DocumentInitialProps } from 'next/document';

interface DecoratedDocumentInitialProps extends DocumentInitialProps {
    themeCssClassName: 'light' | 'dark';
}

class MyDocument extends Document<DecoratedDocumentInitialProps> {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext): Promise<DecoratedDocumentInitialProps> {
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

        const themeCssClassName = ctx?.req?.headers?.cookie?.includes('theme=dark') ? 'dark' : 'light';

        return { ...initialProps, themeCssClassName };
    }

    render() {
        const { themeCssClassName } = this.props;

        return (
            <Html className={themeCssClassName}>
                <Head />
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        );
    }
}

export default MyDocument;
```